# Split with pair of brackets and keep content between

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split a string in a list of strings. Right now i have to split whenever I see any of these characters:  '.', ';', ':', '?', '!', '( )', '[ ]', '{ }' (keep in mind that I have to mantain whatever is inside the brackets).
To solve it I tried to write

```
print(re.split("\(([^)]*)\)|[.,;:?!]\s*", "Hello world,this is(example)"))
```

but as output I get:

```
['Hello world', None, 'this is', 'example', '']
```

Omitting the ' ' at the end that I'll solve later, how can I remove the None that appears in the middle of the list?
By the way I can't iterate in the list another time because the program shall work with huge files and I have to make it as fast as possible.
Also I don't have to necessarily use re.split so everything that works will be just fine!

I'm still new at this so I'm sorry if something is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is fast enough but you could do this:

```
re.sub(r";|,|:|\(|\)|\[|\]|\?|\.|\{|\}|!", " ", "Hello world,this is(example)").split()
```